# No module named 'ebcli.core'

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services

The file code is

```
import sys
import ebcli.core.ebcore

def main():
    return ebcli.core.ebcore.main()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main()
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Debarun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\eb", line 12, in <module>
    import ebcli.core.ebcore
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ebcli.core'
```

Any solutions for the error? Please help

Thank you!

Comment: What is `ebcli`?

Comment: could you go a bit in more detail?